# convert image to byte and split into fragments

Tags: python-3.x, split, byte

I am trying to create a image splitter in python. The idea is to read the image in `'rb'`mode. Firstly is it possible to split the byte stream into fragments and later combine them to produce the original image? if yes how do I go about splitting the file.

Here is my code so far

```
import re

data = open('py.png','rb').read()
image_array = re.split(r'\\',data)
print(image_array)
```

Since these are bytes I cant use `re.split`. How to split the data stored in **data** vairable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking up the Python Imaging Library(http://effbot.org/imagingbook/pil-index.htm) would be a good place to start, possibly combining it with NumPy (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/index.html).

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

im = Image.open('py.png')
image_array = np.array(im)
```

you can then split the image/array with:

```
splitA = image_array[:10,:]
splitB = image_array[11:20,:]
etc...
```